# imageArray[i] = imageItem is incompatible

Tags: javascript

I have been struggling with trying to implement the the answer from TheNoble-Coder for [Difficulty in Understanding Slideshow script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299954/difficulty-in-understanding-slideshow-script).
His "Well if you want..." solution sounds like a very elegant solution for folders containing a varying number of images.
However I have have not been able to get it to work. Using Free JavaScript Editor by Yaldex to debug I get 'Error: Incompatible types' for the line indicated:

```
var place; //For convenience this is best as a global
function imageItem(url) 
{
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    return url;
}
for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    imageArray[i] = imageItem(imageDir + i + ".jpg");   <-----Incompatible 
}
```

I would really appreciate any assistance.

The entire script is:

```
     <script language="JavaScript">
var interval = 4000;
var random_display = 0;
var imageDir = "images/";
var imageNum = - 1;
var place; //For convenience this is best as a global
function imageItem(url) 
{
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    return url;
}
for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    imageArray[i] = imageItem(imageDir + i + ".jpg");
}
function randNum(x, y)
{
   var range = y - x + 1;
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + x;
}
function getNextImage() 
{
    imageNum = (random_display) ? randNum(0, imageArray.length-1) : ((imageNum+1) % imageArray.length);
    return imageArray[imageNum];
}
function getPrevImage()
{
    imageNum = (imageNum-1 >= 0) ? (imageNum-1) : (imageArray.length-1);
    return imageArray[imageNum];
}
function prevImage() 
{
    var image_item = getPrevImage();
    place.src = place.alt = image_item.url;
}
function nextImage() 
{
    var image_item = getNextImage();
    place.src = place.alt = image_item.url;
}
function play() 
{
    nextImage();
    timerID = setTimeout(play, interval);
}
window.onload = function()
{
    place = document.slideImg;
    play();
};

  </script>
```

Comment: Where is `imageArray` declared?

Comment: Per TheNoble-Coder's original code in the boddy tag:

<body> 
 
<img name="slideImg" src="27.jpg" width="500" height="375" border="0"><br /> 
<a href="#" onclick="play()">Play slide show</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp; 
<a href="#" onclick="clearTimeout(timerID)">Pause</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp; 
<a href="#" onclick="clearTimeout(timerID); prevImage();">Previous</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp; 
<a href="#" onclick="clearTimeout(timerID); nextImage();">Next</a> &nbsp; 
 
</body>

BTW I have also tried removing src=27.jpg and this makes no difference.

Comment: I don't see `imageArray` declared anywhere in there.

Comment: I think it is handled by

var place; //For convenience this is best as a global 
function imageItem(url)  
{ 
    var img = new Image(); 
    img.src = url; 
    return url; 
} 

then
window.onload = function(){ 
    place = document['slideImg']; 
    play(); 
}; 

and finally name='slideImg'

...but the actual problem is the Debug fails, and advises that line 33 (indicated above is) incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing `imageArray[i]` and `imageItem(imageDir + i + ".jpg")` to see if it does what you you're expecting from it. I believe that's the key for the solution... :)

Comment: I have tried the following and do not get a print out on the page
  document.writeln(imageArray [i]);
  document.writeln(imageItem(imageDir + i + ".jpg"));

  document.writeln(imageItem);  prints out the following
'function imageItem(url) { var img = new Image; img.src = url; return url; }'

and document.writeln(i);  prints out '0'

and document.writeln(imageDir + i + ".jpg"); prints out 'images/0.jpg'